# Dart fix, Nothing to fix

Tags: flutter, dart

Today I upgraded flutter version from `2.3` to `2.5` and `Dart Analysis` show me new 6k+ hints

By running `dart fix --apply` It just fixes about 200 hints each time, after 10 times of running `dart fix --apply` it show me `Nothing to fix!` but `Dart Analysis` show 4k+ hints